# How to install Gtk# on Ubunu 18.04?

Tags: gui, gtk, c#

Is there any way to install Gtk# on ubuntu 18.04? I'm missing the gnome-desktop-sharp library, which i can't install because it requires gnome-desktop2.

If it's impossible, are there any other good C# GUI frameworks for Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono-based GTK# packages are [available in the *Bionic* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gtk+sharp&searchon=all).

You can start with installing of examples:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-sharp2-examples gtk-sharp3-examples
```

Then run them

```
/usr/share/gtk-sharp2-examples/button.exe
/usr/share/gtk-sharp3-examples/button.exe
```

or view their code

```
xdg-open /usr/share/gtk-sharp2-examples/ButtonApp.cs
xdg-open /usr/share/gtk-sharp3-examples/ButtonApp.cs
```

Also you can download source package of `gtk-sharp2-examples`, edit and compile examples from it:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gtk-sharp2-examples
apt-get source gtk-sharp2-examples
cd gtk-sharp2-2.12.40/
./configure
make -j3

cd sample # go to examples
xdg-open ButtonApp.cs # do some edits edit
make # compile
./button.exe # see changes
```